# Can't find button by classname selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to login to https://ok.ru/

I can't find button by css selector or classname .
I want to click the button

[image]

My code returns error

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button-pro __wide"}

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
    
def login(email, password):
    driver.get(BASE_URL)
    driver.find_element_by_id('field_email').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id('field_password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-pro __wide').click()

login(email, password)
```

**Debugging details**

```
<ipython-input-19-30d48e0af276> in login(email, password)
      6     driver.find_element_by_id('field_email').send_keys(email)
      7     driver.find_element_by_id('field_password').send_keys(password)
----> 8     driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button-pro __wide.button-pro __wide').click()
      9 
     10 login(email, password)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
    596             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
    597         """
--> 598         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
    599 
    600     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button-pro __wide.button-pro __wide"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

P.S
I know that I can use xpath, but I need reliable method that uses same classname or id etc

Comment: did you try with xpath, does it work?

Comment: yes, it works
```driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[5]/div[1]/input').click()```

Comment: notice that it is a bad practice to use absolute XPaths, as you can't guarantee the overall html structure won't change over time, prefer using "//" notation when possible. Otherwise you can also use the `submit()` method after `send_keys()` on the password field.

Comment: How can I fix my question?

Comment: Have you considered adding an html file of sorts that will give you the exact same result and error, so that users here can run it on their own system independently of what is on the site?